# Mean squared error / Max error squared

Tags: mean, standard-error

I'm use this metric for variation that is similar to CV, but it is guaranteed to be on a 0 to 2 scale for positive numbers, where 2 is "all over the place" and 0 is "perfectly even".   Since its dimensionless and bounded, it's useful to me in ways that CV really isn't.

Does this have a standard name?  It's the mean squared error divided by the maximum error squared.    I use it all the time, but don't know if it's called anything:

```
function(v) {(sum((v-mean(v))**2))/((sum(v)-mean(v))**2)}
```

And a skewed version that deals with low-counts:

```
function(v) {(min(2,(max(0,sum(floor(abs(v-mean(v)))**2)-2*sum(v)))/max(1,((sum(v)-mean(v))**2-2*sum(v)))))}
```

It only reports things as "out of whack" when they are out of sync/not balanced enough.   It works perfectly.  When the data are fairly uniform, you get zero.  When there's a spike of some kind (size of the spike relative to length of vector), you get a larger value.

I need to explain *why* I'm using it.   I know that it works, empirically, in my situation, because we get better results than using things like maximum likelihood, or a cutoff with CV alone.   Essentially it signals outliers, which are nicely removed.

But is there a better way of describing these functions for dimensionless coverage summary statistics?

IE: Is there a better function to use to detect a spike proportional to the size of the vector?

Comment: (1) What do you mean by "CV"? (2) The first function does not involve the maximum of anything, despite your description of it, nor are its values capped at $2$.  Is there perhaps a typographical error in it?

Comment: Yes, the first function is capped at 2 for a vector of integers.

Comment: I pasted it into `R` and applied it to a vector of 10 standard normal random variates (after setting the seed to 17).  Output: 2.419989. The claim for integers falls when these are multiplied by 1000 and truncated (*via* `floor`); the output is 5.024757.

Comment: Sorry, I was only using positive integers.

Comment: Any positive numbers are bounded by 0->2, they don't have to be integers.  I tried a million or so random ones.